# Divide into hourly partitions and inset data by partitions

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a procedure that runs every five minutes from 8 am to 11:59 pm, inserts data into a table, deletes today's data from SAS, and inserts it again from the table. And the problem is that every 5 minutes there is more and more data, if at 8 am it starts working with 100 data, then by 11:59 pm there are already more than a million data, and constantly inserting and deleting data takes a lot of database resources:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ETLT#SOFT_CALLS AS
    p_dt date;
BEGIN
    p_dt := trunc(sysdate);

TRUNCATE#('SOFT_CALLS');

INSERT /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel(16)*/
INTO SOFT_CALLS(CALLID,
            START_TIME,
        DURATION,
        FIRST_QUESTION,
        SECOND_QUESTION,
        CLIENT_ID,
        CONTRACT_ID,
        CLIENT_DWH_ID)
SELECT /*+ parallel(16)*/ 
    a.CALLID as CALLID,
    a.START_TIME as START_TIME,
    a.DURATION AS DURATION,
    b.FIRST_QUESTION AS FIRST_QUESTION,
    b.SECOND_QUESTION AS SECOND_QUESTION,
    a.CLIENT_ID AS CLIENT_ID,
    a.CONTRACT_ID AS CONTRACT_ID,
    sch.CLIENT_DWH_ID AS CLIENT_DWH_ID
FROM CALL_DETAIL a
LEFT JOIN DIALOGE_ONLINE b
  ON b.CALL_ID = a.CALL_ID
LEFT JOIN MINT_HIST sch
  ON sch.DATE_INS >= p_dt
  AND sch.ID = a.CONTRACT_ID
WHERE trunc(a.START_TIME) = p_dt;
COMMIT;


DELETE FROM SASUSER.SOFT_CALLS@DWHSAS
WHERE trunc(START_TIME) = p_dt;
COMMIT;

INSERT /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel(16)*/
INTO SASUSER.SOFT_CALLS@DWHSAS
SELECT * FROM SOFT_CALLS;
COMMIT;
```

Whether it is possible to divide the table into hour partitions? Let's say at 10 am, it inserts data into the table not for trunc(sysdate), but only for the created partition. If the procedure works from 8 am to 11:59 pm, does it need to be divided into 16 hourly partitions?

And is it necessary to drop these partitions at the end of the procedure? Would this be a viable option?

Previously, I did not work with hourly partitions and how to insert or delete data on partitions at all, I would be grateful for advice or help.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Version oracle 19c

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

1. If you record the maximum value of START_TIME (the full value, i.e. not truncated) somewhere and read that back in, you could then process only the rows where START_TIME >= (recorded max value of start time from previous run).
2. Perhaps you could add a column to CALL_DETAIL called `PROCESSED`, set that to "NO" when you insert a new row into CALL_DETAIL, and set it to "YES" if you've processed that CALL_DETAIL row. Then, in the query, only fetch CALL_DETAIL rows where PROCESSED = "NO". You might be able to use an ON INSERT trigger on SOFT_CALLS to do the update of CALL_DETAIL.

Comment: I was able to create a table with hourly partitions, but I just don’t know how to write a condition in the procedure so that it itself determines the time in hours and inserts it into the desired partition

Comment: If your partitions are based on the START_TIME column then you don't need to do anything different - the value of START_TIME will determine which partition the inserted data goes into, and (if automatic partition generation is set up) the necessary partitions will be created when needed. If you've partitioned your table on something else I'd need to understand the "something else" in order to make a reasonable recommendation.