# Divide into hourly partition #2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've asked a similar question before but couldn't figure it out([Divide into hourly partitions and inset data by partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73381519/divide-into-hourly-partitions-and-inset-data-by-partitions)).

I created a table with hourly partitions, and when inserting data, it correctly divides by hourly partitions:

```
create table SOFT_CALLS(    
  callid               VARCHAR2(90),
  start_time           date not null,
  start_time_h         as (to_char(start_time, 'HH24')),
  duration             NUMBER,
  first_question       VARCHAR2(4000),
  second_question      VARCHAR2(4000),
  client_id            VARCHAR2(20),
  contract_id          VARCHAR2(20),
  client_dwh_id        VARCHAR2(20) 
)
partition by list (start_time_h)
(
partition p_08 values ('08'),
partition p_09 values ('09'),
partition p_10 values ('10'),
partition p_11 values ('11'),
partition p_12 values ('12'),
partition p_13 values ('13'),
partition p_14 values ('14'),
partition p_15 values ('15'),
partition p_16 values ('16'),
partition p_17 values ('17'),
partition p_18 values ('18'),
partition p_19 values ('19'),
partition p_20 values ('20'),
partition p_21 values ('21'),
partition p_22 values ('22'),
partition p_23 values ('23')
);
```

The logic of the procedure should be as follows: so that it inserts data into the table for trunc(sysdate - 1/24, 'hh') and trunc(sysdate + 1/24, 'hh') and then transfers the same data to SAS and at the end simply drop these partitions so that the procedure does not do this for the entire trunc (sysdate) every five minutes, so resource consumption will decrease.

It is necessary that the table stores data in hourly partitions, that is, it will not truncate all the data each time and refill for the whole day, but only drop partitions for the last hour and also insert data without losing data for the hours that have already passed.

But the problem is that list partitions cannot be dropped during this period trunc(sysdate - 1/24, 'hh') and trunc(sysdate + 1/24, 'hh').

What other examples are there for dividing a table into hourly partitions and so that in the end there would be no problems dropping them over the period that I indicated? I've looked all over the internet, but I haven't been able to find any specific information.

Comment: You may use interval partitioning. It will not reuse old partitions and you may drop them when they are not required anymore

Comment: Use interval partition. Or truncate the partitions of unneeded data, otherwise you have to create the partitions again and again.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit maybe there are other solutions, or solve the problem without using partitions?

Comment: I think this is at least the 3rd time, you ask more or less the same question. And I still have no clue what you are looking for.

Comment: you're right bro, it's also unpleasant for me to ask the same question several times, im done with this task